# How to debug sidekiq frontend?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sidekiq

I have an app where sidekiq is a very important part of the whole architecture, and we're using a couple of extensions/plugins to get the job done.

```
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sidetiq', github: 'tobiassvn/sidetiq'
gem 'sidekiq-failures', github: 'mhfs/sidekiq-failures'
gem 'sidekiq-middleware'
gem 'sinatra', require: false
gem 'slim'
```

sidekiq-failures is apparently working (I'm 99% confident it is) but unfortunately sidekiq's frontend on /failures is returning a 500 Internal server error **only** in production (lucky me) without logging anything (I enabled all logging options in the RoR production env).
Only that page and only in production.

How can I debug this problem? Any suggestions?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I think this was a temporary issue with sidekiq-failures that [was resolved here](https://github.com/mhfs/sidekiq-failures/issues/87#issuecomment-46013842).